# How to split a number in python and add them

Tags: python

I'm working on a lucky name numbers game, and I am able to get the number from the name by running it through a custom-made function, but I cannot seem to add them together.

My code so far:

```
num = 0

def main():
    name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    for letter in name:
        if letter == 'a' or letter == 'j' or letter == 's':
            num = num + 1
        if letter == 'b' or letter == 'k' or letter == 't':
            num = num + 2
        if letter == 'c' or letter == 'l' or letter == 'u':
            num = num + 3
        if letter == 'd' or letter == 'm' or letter == 'v':
            num = num + 4
        if letter == 'e' or letter == 'n' or letter == 'w':
            num = num + 5
        if letter == 'f' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'x':
            num = num + 6
        if letter == 'g' or letter == 'p' or letter == 'y':
            num = num + 7
        if letter == 'h' or letter == 'q' or letter == 'z':
            num = num + 8
        if letter == 'i' or letter == 'r':
            num = num + 9
        getDigitSum()

def getDigitSum(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        num, remainder = divmod(num, 10)
        sum += remainder
    return sum

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several obvious errors to this one:

1. You aren't saving num after each for-loop run through. Since you called `getDigitSum(num)` with no arguments, there should be an error. Even if it did work (aka you changed the `getDigitSum()` to `getDigitSum(num)`, it will still fail to work because num is not preserved after each run. **TL:DR;** change the line `getDigitSum()` in your main to `num = getDigitSum(num)`.
2. You aren't outputting anything in this code. the sum is not being printed after the program finishes. So, after you change the line `getDigitSum()` you should also include `print(sum)` after the for loop, inside `main()`.

So, your code would look like this:

```
num = 0

def main():
    name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    for letter in name:
        if letter == 'a' or letter == 'j' or letter == 's':
            num = num + 1
        if letter == 'b' or letter == 'k' or letter == 't':
            num = num + 2
        if letter == 'c' or letter == 'l' or letter == 'u':
            num = num + 3
        if letter == 'd' or letter == 'm' or letter == 'v':
            num = num + 4
        if letter == 'e' or letter == 'n' or letter == 'w':
            num = num + 5
        if letter == 'f' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'x':
            num = num + 6
        if letter == 'g' or letter == 'p' or letter == 'y':
            num = num + 7
        if letter == 'h' or letter == 'q' or letter == 'z':
            num = num + 8
        if letter == 'i' or letter == 'r':
            num = num + 9
        num = getDigitSum(num)
    print(num)

def getDigitSum(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        num, remainder = divmod(num, 10)
        sum += remainder
    return sum

main()
```

Please read up on StackOverflow's [Asking Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question, too.

Answer (score 1):

`getDigitSum` is a function that takes in one parameter, `num` that it does some calculation with and returns a number.

You not only are not passing in any arguments to it, but also not storing its return value anywhere.

Replace `getDigitSum()` with something like `print(getDigitSum(num))`.

I'm also pretty sure that line should not be inside your for loop, but I don't exactly understand the rules of your program.

In the future, you should read up on StackOverflow's [Asking Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question doesn't describe your problem very well, and is not very well formatted, and so is difficult to understand.